# ImageSprites Not Moving on 'Dynamic' Screens

Tags: android, canvas, app-inventor

I am with a really serious help and want to know if you can help me.

As App Inventor has some 'Capacity Issues' I cannot create lots of Screens in my project. So, one of my screens is a 'Dynamic One', which receives a StartValue from another one and acts according to this value.

This 'Dynamic Screen' has one Canvas and Two ImageSprites. Depending on which value this Screen receives, a different background image is used in the Canvas component and I have to move the two image Sprites to different positions in the Canvas. I did this because these two ImageSprites are buttons in specific parts of the image that will open an ActivityStarter that runs the youtube application in a given URL. The ImageSprites positions, the canvas background and video that will played when the canvas is pressed will depend of course on the input.

My problem here is that I cannot move these sprites this way (dynamicaly depending on StartValue the Screen receives), it simply doesn't work (I think it is a bug). I tried everything, setting ImageSprite.x, ImageSprite.y, use functions ImageSprite.Moveto, ImageSprite.PointTowards, it simply doesn't work if the Screen receives an StartValue.

If I am on 'Blocks' tab and click with right button on the function ImageSprite.MoveTo and select 'Do It', the ImageSprites can be moved. Also, if I access the 'Design' tab and inform which Background will be used in Canvas, the ImageSprites are also moved without problems (I don't want this scenario, I want the background changing depending on StartValue).

Below is my 'Blocks' Tab, what is wrong here? is this a bug? can you please help me with this issue? how can I move the ImageSprites on a Canvas depending on which StartValue a screen receives?

[image: My Blocks Tab]

Comment: you can find the answer to your question in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/uVzi85UZQkM/vILK71TCKAAJ)